# How to decouple local directory and Heroku project

Tags: django, database, heroku, local, coupling

I am developing an app with Django and I successfully pushed it on Heroku.
This app has a postgres database and a form to allow users to fill the database.
I have coupled the local directory and Heroku, so that both if I run the server by command prompt, or if I access the app, and submit the form, my database get changed.

Now I want to make some experiments on the local database without changing the one on Heroku.
Is it possible?
Can I do it by just commenting the database URL in settings.py ?

I have searched for this matter on Google but I don't know the name it, so that I cound not find proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a question of "decoupling" directories. It is because you are trying to use sqlite on Heroku, and you have added the sqlite file to your git repo.

You *cannot* use sqlite on Heroku; use the postgres add-on. Additionally, your sqlite file must not be in source control.

Comment: I am using a postgres database

Comment: So what's the problem? You should have a local database for local use, and the one on Heroku for use on Heroku. How are you even accessing the Heroku one from your dev machine?

Comment: I think I coupled the two database by pasting the database uri (Heroku: app>config). But then I did some other things following a tutorial. I don't know if it is sufficient to cancel the uri line in settings.py

Comment: You should be using django_heroku (or the older dj_database_url) to configure your settings via environment variables. You shouldn't be hard-coding the database parameters anywhere.